# Why is my Rust RSI calculation different from the TradingView indicator?

Tags: rust, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I am attempting to replicate the RSI indicator value from TradingView using Rust and the Mexc API, but the value displayed is incorrect. Can you help me identify what I am doing wrong?

```rs
async fn get_symbol_rsi(client: Client, symbol: &str) -> AppResult<f64> {
    let candles: Klines = client
        .get(format!(
            "https://contract.mexc.com/api/v1/contract/kline/{symbol}?interval=Min15"
        ))
        .send()
        .await?
        .json()
        .await?;

    let mut closes = candles
        .data
        .close
        .into_iter()
        .rev() // So it shows from new candles
        .take(15) // take the last 15 new candles (1 more because of the first one?)
        .rev(); // reverse it back to the original order older to newer

    // Get the gains and losses percentages
    let mut gains = Vec::new();
    let mut losses = Vec::new();

    let prev_close = closes.next().unwrap();
    for close in closes {
        let diff = close - prev_close;

        if diff > 0.0 {
            gains.push(diff);
            losses.push(0.0);
        } else {
            gains.push(0.0);
            losses.push(diff.abs());
        }
    }

    // Calculate the RSI based on RMA
    let alpha = 1.0 / 14.0;
    let mut rma_gains = gains[0];
    let mut rma_losses = losses[0];

    for i in 1..14 {
        rma_gains = alpha * gains[i] + (1.0 - alpha) * rma_gains;
        rma_losses = alpha * losses[i] + (1.0 - alpha) * rma_losses;
    }

    let rs = rma_gains / rma_losses;
    let rsi = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + rs));

    Ok(rsi)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference from what I see is that you are using a Simple Moving Average for the `avg_up` and `avg_down` variables.

TradingView uses a modified Exponential Moving Average called [Relative Moving Average (RMA)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta.rma) for use in their [Relative Strength Index (RSI)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta.rsi) for those variables.

The difference is in the alpha variable:

Where EMA has `alpha = 2 / (length + 1)`

RMA has `alpha = 1 / length`

Below is a function for RMA in Rust:

```
fn rma(price_ndarray: &Array1<f32>, period: usize) -> Array1<f32>{
    let length = price_ndarray.len() - period +1;
    let mut result = Array1::<f32>::zeros(length);
    result[0] = price_ndarray.slice(s![0..period]).sum();
    for i in 1..length{
        result[i] = result[i-1]+(price_ndarray[i+period-1]-result[i-1])*(1.0/(period as f32));
    }
    
    result
}
```

Comment: thanks, but is there an alternative without ndarray crate? with just the standard library?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Rust (mainly used it to compare speeds with Python, therefore the ndarray), but here is a link for [EMA from the Technical Analysis for Rust (ta) library](https://github.com/greyblake/ta-rs/blob/master/src/indicators/exponential_moving_average.rs). The alpha variable is declared on line 71 as `k`, so just change it to `k: 1.0 / period as f64,`.

Comment: so I applied RMA calculations but it still doesn't show the correct value can I check why?

Comment: One other reason why an indicator can be different is if the values of the OHLC data are different. Check if the data from Mexc API is different from the TradingView data. If the data is the same, further checks need to be done.

Comment: Yea the klines are the same.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot indicating the differences?

Comment: I don't think there is a need for a screenshot but the data is like the tradingview is showing the RSI of doge is 36.66 (default settings) but this functions shows its 11.